# How are POSIX Threads implemented on Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I was wondering if threads created via the pthreads library are actually kernel-level threads or user-space threads that have nothing to do with the kernel? I have heard mutually exclusive opinions about this, so I want to know the truth.

Comment: NPTL follows a 1:1 model, simple and effective :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before Linux 2.6 they were essentially userspace threads, separate processes which were glued together, because the kernel had no real thread support. Edit: There was some limited support for kernel level threads (a clone() function) before 2.6, but it wasn't used with posix threads, only with an alternative thread library called linuxthreads.
Since the arrival of *NPTL* (Native Posix Thread Library) the are kernel threads.

Comment: If you are referring to LinuxThreads, those are kernel-level too.

Comment: Just mentioned it while you were commenting ;-) But I was referring to posix threads, as the OP asked, and they were not kernel level at that time

Comment: LinuxThreads were kernel-level, each thread corresponded to a kernel-level scheduling entity (task).

Answer (score 6):

Threads created by `pthread_create()` on Linux have always been kernel-level threads. LinuxThreads didn't comply fully with POSIX (threads in a same process had different pid's, signal handling was different than what POSIX requires, ...), so NPTL was created to fix those issues.

There are libraries that implement user-level threads (e.g: GNU pth, the p is for *Portable*), but they don't use the POSIX thread API.